# Migrating Wordpress multisite to single sites

Tags: php, wordpress

I am moving 11 sites that are currently in a Multisite configuration in an internal network, and would like to migrate them to WP Engine as single individual sites.

I would like to use phpmyadmin to export the data site by site. I am using HeidiSQL to connect to the database and exporting as sql. I will need to manipulate the data, turning it from a multisite to a single install.

What specifically should I be modifying?

-removing site id (i.e. wp_17 to wp_)
-what else?

Answer (score 0):

I would test the plugins first before I do the migration, I know 11 sites will take too much time. 
although keep in mind that 99% of the popular plugins has been tested to a newer vision of WP. 
Don't forget to change the Wp_config from multi-sites to individual.